# XML CDATA not working with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I want to output an image using xslt. The src attribute will be comming from an xml node>

Example

```
<images>
     <![CDATA[/images/sample_image.png]]>
</images
```

in my xslt i outputted the image with the following code below but im getting a broken image.

```
<xsl:element name="img">    
   <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="//images"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

but when i tried to output the image by hard coding the src, it worked.

```
 <xsl:element name="img">   
       <xsl:attribute name="src">/images/sample_image.png</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
```

is there any reason why the first code doesn't worked?

Comment: Please show your output.

Comment: Hi Francis.. im getting a broken image like when the image or path defined in the src attribute cant be found. something like that

Comment: It shouldn't matter to an XSLT stylesheet whether the data is in a CDATA section or not, the XSLT data model does not distinguish such markup syntax details at all. So the error is most likely elsewhere, perhaps it is a namespace issue.

Comment: The only issue I can think of besides namespaces is the white space before and after the CDATA section, I am not sure how browsers handle that if you don't strip it so consider using `<img src="{normalize-space(//images)}"/>`, that might fix it.

Comment: Fine, I have put that suggestion in an answer you could mark as answering the problem so that stackoverflow shows your questions as being solved.

Comment: @unknown, don't describe your output, print it out. I mean the actual xml output, not "this image is broken". You probably would have seen the whitespace problem right away if you had done that.

Answer (score 3):

Try to strip the white space with e.g. `<img src="{normalize-space(//images)}"/>`, that might help.